# Git rebase vs merge.If git rebase will make tags missing?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

```
A-B-C-D-E-F     master
    \
     H-I-J      feature
       |
      tag v1.0
```

what if I `reabse master feature`?  Will the tag1.0 be missing?

Comment: Did you try it? What did you expect and why?

Comment: I am not sure.I expect the tag is the same as when I execute  git tag. I will try now.I jus read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing which make me puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

The tag won't be missing but it will probably not do what you want. That is the tag will stay on `I`:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F          master
    |     \
    \      H'-I'-J'  feature 
     H-I-J
       |
      tag v1.0
```

Try it:

```
$ git init
$ for c in {A..F}; do touch $c; git add $c; git commit -m $c; done
$ git checkout -b feature HEAD^{/C}
$ for c in {H..J}; do touch $c; git add $c; git commit -m $c; done
$ git tag 'tag-v1.0' feature^{/I}

$ git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline
* d782b9d (HEAD -> feature) J
* c0df2db (tag: tag-v1.0) I
* 2a9fb01 H
| * 3018edf (master) F
| * e0eabe0 E
| * daab573 D
|/
* 8ebf4bb C
* 82be26d B
* 8379c01 A
$ git rebase master feature

$ git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline
* 091cf03 (HEAD -> feature) J
* 6327f84 I
* 69123dd H
* 3018edf (master) F
* e0eabe0 E
* daab573 D
| * c0df2db (tag: tag-v1.0) I
| * 2a9fb01 H
|/
* 8ebf4bb C
* 82be26d B
* 8379c01 A
```

Notes:

`HEAD^{/C}` reference the most recent commit reachable from HEAD whose message matches `C`, see [gitrevisions](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> `<rev>^{/<text>}`, e.g. `HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}`
>
> A suffix `^` to a revision parameter, followed by a brace pair that contains a text led by a slash, is the same as the `:/fix nasty bug` syntax below except that it returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from the `<rev>` before `^`.

Comment: The tag won't be missing, I just try it.Your answer make me more clear about git usage.Thanks a lot.

Comment: For those (like me) who haven’t seen the `HEAD^{/C}` reference before, it is used to find the most recent commit reachable from `HEAD` whose message matches `C`. See [gitrevisions(7)](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: @cmbuckley In my humble opinion, just edit the answer instead of leaving a comment. Your comment contains valuable information and other readers will benefit.